# Cannot Set Property ... Which Only Has Getter (javascript es6)

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, typeerror, getter-setter

So I have a simple Javascript class

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x === undefined ? 0 : x;
    }

    get x() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

When a MyClass is created, I want it's x to be set to the value passed in as a parameter. After this, I do not want it to be able to be changed, so I have intentionally not made a set x() method.

However, I guess I must be missing something fundamental, as this is giving me the "Cannot set property ... which only has getter" error.

How do I assign a value to x without creating a setter method?

Comment: You can't. A property must either be a plain property or else a getter/setter property. (I think; checking the spec)

Comment: Also your code as written will fail, because the reference to `this.x` in the getter will be understood as a function call to the getter, meaning infinite recursion.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a couple problems here.

When you make a getter via `get x()` you are causing `this.x` to result in calling the getter, which will recurse indefinitely due to your `get x()` doing `this.x`.

Replace your references to `this.x` with `this._x` in this code like this:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(x) {
        this._x = x === undefined ? 0 : x;
    }

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }
}
```

Now your encapsulated `x` which is now `_x` will not be confused for a call to the getter via `this.x`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

If you want an instance property to be read-only, then make it not writable:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(x) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "x", { value: x || 0 });
    }
}
```

A property can either be a "simple" property, as all properties were in the days of yore, or a getter/setter property.

When a property is a getter/setter property, *all* references to the property go through the getter or setter, *including* from within the getter and setter functions. Thus to store the property you need to use an alternative property name or (better) a Symbol instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an immutable property `a` within your class definition, this os one way to do so with the method JavaScript gives is to do this (using `Object.defineProperty()`).

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(x) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'a', {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: false,
      writable: false,
      value: x || 'empty'
    });
  }

}
let o = new MyClass('Hello');

console.log(o.a);
o.a = 'Will not change';
console.log(o.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass 
{
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x === undefined ? 0 : x;
    }

    get() {
        return this.x;
    } 

    set(x) { return this.x = x;}
}
```